# render NUTS data to a map in a browser with d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm using the [Nomenclature of Units for Territorial Statistics (NUTS)](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/administrative-units-statistical-units/nuts#nuts13) data of national subregions (*i.e. states/departments, administrative regions smaller than nations but bigger than cities*). I've taken them from the official website as Shapefiles.

Next, I converted them to GeoJSON using the following command:

`ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON europe_admin_sub_units.json NUTS_RG_01M_2013.shp`

Now what I want to do is simple render this in the browser to get a sense of what it looks like.

I've tried this simple script but it didn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

/* CSS goes here. */

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 1160;

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .scale(500)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("data.json", function(error, uk) {
  svg.append("path")
      .attr("d", path);
});

</script>
```

However, I don't understand why it didn't work.

There were no errors in the console of my browser. I'm using Chrome.

[Here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/s-matthew-english/scaling-brain/master/data.json) is the data I'm using, in essence though it just looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
    { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "NUTS_ID": "AT", "STAT_LEVL_": 0, "SHAPE_AREA": 10.0385472864, "SHAPE_LEN": 27.774664036600001 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates":
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

First, your GeoJSON file is HUGE. Rendering this in a browser is going to be very slow. That may not be an issue if you just want to take a look at the resulting shapes, but otherwise you'll need to simplify it. This is easy enough with ogr2ogr -simplify.

Second, *path* is a function, so you'll need to call it with some geographical features to see anything.

https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Geo-Paths.md

```
d3.json("data.json", function(error, uk) {
  svg.append("path")
      .attr("d", path(uk));
});
```

... will get you something, but I'm not sure if it is what you are looking for.

Also, if you just want to see the shapes, you could use QGIS (http://www.qgis.org/en/site/), which is free and great for previewing and manipulating shape files.